# Can't run Python program with accented letters using Emacs

Tags: python-3.x, emacs, editor

I am using the latest versions of Python and Emacs. I use Emacs as my editor for Python and it works great (keep in mind that I've only been doing simple programs so far). However, when I put a letter with an accent, e.g. é, Emacs will save it but then when I click on the program it won't run. It just opens and closes a page quickly. I then opened it with IDLE and it gave the following:

[image]

If I click OK then it will run. But if I go back and edit it with Emacs it shows it as Ã© instead of é. To make things more odd, I had existing Python programs that I made with Atom with the letter é and they all run without having to convert it to UTF-8. Any thoughts?

Comment: What encoding are you using to save the file?  Unless you have a good reason, use utf-8.  Using `emacs -q`, Emacs saves as utf-8, so maybe you (or some package you've installed) have set your default encoding configured to something else.

Comment: @jpkotta what do you mean by emacs -q? And I do have this (set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8) in the ~/.emacs

Comment: `emacs -q` starts Emacs without any user configuration.  If you can't reproduce a problem with `emacs -q`, it's almost certainly due to something in your config, not in Emacs itself.

Comment: `set-keyboard-coding-system` affects input coding, and then only in terminal (not graphical) frames.  You want to set file encoding (what encoding is used when writing files to disk).  Try `(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)`.

Comment: @jpkotta That seemed to work! I will update later if I have any more issues.